# Command read in bash with typing on start some characters ready to use backspace

Tags: bash

I'm learning in bash while my internship and I want to use "read" command in a different way like normal it used to be. 
I'll try my best to describe what I'm trying to do, but my English isn't perfect.

What I want it is while typing in server address I don't want for every time type in `https://`. What I already did is like you see:

```
read -p "JamfProURL: https://" jssURL
```

and

```
jssURL="https://${jssURL}"
```

And it works correctly. But what I want to get is an option to delete that "https://" to replace it for "http://" while executing script. That's only example. What I wanted for this code, it is and works fine. I started thinking about other cases.

I will be grateful for your help. If I can ask, pls give me clearly examples or edited my example of code.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter url Jamf server, e.g: jamfaddress:8443"

read -p "JamfProURL: https://" jssURL

echo "Enter your JamfPro username"

    read -p "login: " jssuser

echo "Enter your JamfPro password"

    read  -p "password: " jssPass

echo "Enter computer serial number: "

    read -p "serial_number: " SERIAL

jssURL="https://${jssURL}"
```

Comment: if you can access those urls through your system, you may automate the process of deciding if the url is http or https, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168736/using-bash-to-determine-if-url-is-http-or-https

Comment: Why make the value include `https` in the first place if you really just want `http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable `read` to use the Readline library with `-e`, you can "preload" the buffer using the `-i` option.

```
$ read -e -i "https://" -p "JamfProURL: " jssURL  <<< foobar
$ echo "$jssURL"
https://foobar
```

Note, however, this does *not* work if you redirect standard input; `-e` appears to only enable Readline if the input is from a terminal.

Comment: That's what I wanted, but yeah. It doesn't work in terminal on MacOS but on ubuntu is ok.

Comment: `-i` was introduced in `bash` version 4; macOS continues to ship `bash` 3.2. You might want to install a newer version of `bash` yourself instead of using the pre-shipped version.

Comment: Awesome, it's working right now.
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

echo "Enter url Jamf server, e.g: jamfaddress:8443"
 read -e -i "https://" -p "JamfProURL: " jssURL
I installed ver. 5.0 and it's working properly. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your option is via a variable value.
In my example, I will use a variable.

```
if ${option} == "Y"; then
    jssURL="https://${jssURL}"
else
    jssURL="http://${jssURL}"
fi
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just replace the `https://` to `http://`, you can use

`jssURL=${jssURL/"https://"/"http://"}`

And that way you can continue to use the variable jssURL with that part changed.

Hope that helped!